# High-degree pieces of graded ideal with coprime generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, graded-rings

(I have a couple of questions about graded ideals and I would appreciate any help/ideas anyone may have on the following. I had posted this one earlier, but nothing came of it, so deleted it, trimmed it a bit, and reposting it.)

Let $R = \mathbb{R}[x, y]$, and consider ideal $I = (a, b)$, with $a, b \in R$ homogeneous polynomials of degree $\bar{n}$.

**Q1**. If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, then for sufficiently high degree $I_n = (x,y)^n$.

**Q2**. If $\gcd(a, b) = x^k$, then for sufficiently high degree $I_n = x^k(x,y)^{n-k}$.

---

**My approach:**

**A1**. I suppose that showing $x^iy^{n-i} \in I$, $0 \leq i \leq n$, for $n \gg 1$ will work, but not sure how to follow through with this idea.

**A2**. (Assuming that **Q1** has been answered.)

$$
\gcd(a,b) = x^k \Rightarrow \gcd(a/x^k, b/x^k) = 1
$$
Then, for $m \gg 1$, $x^iy^{m-i} \in (a/x^k, b/x^k)$, $0 \leq i \leq m$.
Thus, for $n \gg 1$, noting that elements of $I_n$ must be multiples of $x^k$, we have using **Q1** that $I_n = x^k(x,y)^{n-k}$.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=1$, then $I=R$, since there exist $f,g\in R$ such that $fa+gb=1$. This shows that $I_n=(x,y)^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. It seems to me that this solves your Question **Q1**.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it does not hold in $R = \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. For example, $gcd(x^2, y) = 1$ but $(x^2, y) \neq R$, and only for $n \geq 2$ do we have $I_n = (x,y)^n$.

Comment: @user213008 Playing off your comment, maybe **Q1** is not true in general. Would it help to assume that $a$ and $b$ have been obtained by homogenization of polynomials (of different degree) $a', b' \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $gcd(a', b') = 1$? (That would mean that $(a', b') = \mathbb{R}[x]$.)

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the confusion. What I said is restricted to principal ideal domains, I guess.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by $I_n$. Maybe the $n$th graded part of $I$? If yes, then $I_n=I\cap R_n$ and I can't figure out how this equals the ideal $(x,y)^n$.

Comment: @user26857 Yes, I mean $I_n = I \cap R_n$, and by $I_n = (x, y)^n$, I meant $I_n = (x, y)^n \cap R_n$. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption**:

$a, b$ are obtained by homogenization of univariate polynomials $a', b'\in \mathbb{R}[x] = R'$ with $\gcd(a', b') = 1$.

**Solution**

Then, for all $i \geq 0$, there exist $f_i', g_i' \in R'$ such that,
$$
 f_i'(x) a'(x) + g_i'(x) b'(x) = x^i.
$$
Therefore, upon homogenization in degree $m \geq i$,
$$
 y^{m} f_i'(x/y) a'(x/y) + y^m g_i'(x/y) b'(x/y) = y^{m-i}x^i,
$$
Then, since the degree of $a$ and $b$ is $\bar{n}$, and assuming that $p = \max_i(\max(\deg(f_i'), \deg(g_i')))$, we have for all $i \geq 0$,
$$
 y^{p + \bar{n}} \left(f_i'(x/y) a'(x/y) + g_i'(x/y) b'(x/y)\right) = y^{p+\bar{n}-i}x^i,\\
 f_i(x,y)a(x,y) + g_i(x,y)b(x,y)=y^{p+\bar{n}-i}x^i,
$$
where $f_i, g_i$ are the homogenizations of $f_i', g_i'$ in degree $p$. And therefore, for all $n \geq p+\bar{n}$, $I_n = (x, y)^n \cap R_n = R_n$.